# What's the best way to convert data objects to new schemas?

Tags: mongodb, architecture, solr

I find myself writing a lot of scripts to transfer data between similar schemas, specifically from MongoDB to Solr and I'm looking to minimize the repition. Since the data is coming in from a variety of sources there isn't a feasible way to standardize the schema in Mongo. A lot of my lines end up looking like:

```
solr['field1'] = mongo['field1']
solr['field2'] = mongo['field2']
solr['field1'] = modify(mongo['field1'])
...
```

Is there any sort of design concept for this sort of scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about doing something like this (it is not a code, just an example):

```
function mongo2solr(unmodifiedFields, modifiedFields){
  solr = new empty associative array
  for every i in unmodifiedField:
     solr[i] = mongo(i)

  for every i in modifiedField:
     solr[i] = modiry(mongo(i))
}
```

and then to run one function with `solr = mongo2solr(['field1', 'field2'], ['field3'])`